# How to get multiple table rows to appear/dissapear using onchange

Tags: php, javascript, html, onchange, getelementbyid

I have an option in my form which if the user answer yes would then display a divved area.

However I have changed my layout etc and because my form deals with statistical data I thought I would use some tables for some parts.

So I was wondering how I would get three table rows to append to a table using onchange function.

However the getelementbyID only works with one element so only one of my rows is displayed.

Here is what code I have so far:

```
 <table>
      <tr>
      <th>
    <select name="dosage" id="dosage" style="display:block;" onchange="document.getElementById('dosagearea').style.display = this.options.selectedIndex ? 'block' : 'none'">
     </th>
     </tr>


    <?php
//this code generates input fields using codeigntier
                                echo '<tr id="dosagearea">', '<td>', form_label('Emitted µmGy','dosage_emitted'), '</td>', '<td>', form_input ('dosage_emitted', set_value('dosage_emitted')) ,'</td>', '</tr>';
                                echo '<tr id="dosagearea">', '<td>', form_label('Absorbed mGy2','dosage_absorbed'), '</td>', '<td>', form_input ('dosage_absorbed', set_value('dosage_absorbed')) ,'</td>', '</tr>';
                                echo '<tr id="dosagearea">', '<td>', form_label('Dosage Period (mins)','dosage_time'), '</td>', '<td>', form_input ('dosage_time', set_value('dosage_period')), '</td>', '</tr>';
                        ?>

    </table>
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: why do you have the same id for all those three `tr` elements?

Comment: So they will get displayed when onchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you really don't want to have multiple elements with he same id (id should be unique).  You could use class instead. My expertise is with jquery which would make this a snap, but there are functions that implement "getelementbyclass" behavior you could use

Comment: There, Jonah pasted one for you

Comment: Thanks all the other answers did not make sense to me so i just repeated the code 3 times in my onchange and made each ID unique. :)

Answer (score 1):

Dont use getElementById, use getElementByClassName, because multiple elements can have the same class name. And to make sure it works in IE, add this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName = function(class_name)
{
    var all = this.getElementsByTagName('*');
    var matchArray = new Array();
    var re = new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)" + class_name + "(?:\\s|$)");
    for (var i = 0, l = all.length; i < l; i++)
    {
        if (re.test(all[i].className))
            matchArray.push(all[i]);
    }
    return matchArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <select name="dosage" id="dosage" style="display:block;" onchange="toggleShowHide(this.options.selectedIndex, ['id1', 'id2', 'id3']);">

<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleShowHide(idx, arrIDs) {
    var display = idx ? 'block' : 'none';
    for(var x=0; x<arrIDs.length; x++)
        document.getElementById(arrIDs[x]).style.display = display;
}
</script>
```